# How to set up console application to not use GetService every time you need an instance

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, console-application

I'm trying to understand how DI processes work in .net core, and basically every basic example is like:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var collection = new ServiceCollection();
            collection.AddScoped<IBusiness, Business>();
            var provider = collection.BuildServiceProvider();
            //getting an instance is through GetService<>()
            IBusiness biz = provider.GetService<IBusiness>();
        }
    }

    public class Business : IBusiness
    {
        public void DoSomeBusiness()
        {
            Console.Write("This is very serious business stuff");
        }
    }

    public interface IBusiness
    {
        void DoSomeBusiness();
    }
```

It's pretty straight forward - want to instantiate some service, use povider.GetService().

On other hand, in asp.net applications you do not need to explicitly call GetService, application is just injecting needed object whenever you refer it's interface, like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IBoardGameRepository _boardGameRepository;


        public HomeController(IBoardGameRepository boardGameRepository)
        {
            _boardGameRepository = boardGameRepository;
        }


        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var boardGames = _boardGameRepository.GetAllBoardGames();
            //do some logic and return boardagames into view
        }
    }
```

I never found information on how to step up from calling GetService in my console app to using automatic injection like in asp.net. Is it something obvious and I can not figure out it?

Answer (score 0):

**I think this is useful for you**
If you know somthing about **Design Pattern** I think you can use **Facade Design Pattern**

so for more information I suggest to read


[Facade Design Pattern In C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/facade-design-pattern-using-c-sharp/)

but I wanna say how will it work for you .

you shoulde create another class ...
just following code

```
    Public class FacadeClass 
    { 
       private readonly IBusiness _business;
       
       public FacadeClass () 
       { 
         _business = new Business();
       }

       ***Write your methode here***

    }
```

and then use that in your project . following code ...

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var facadeForClient = new FacadeClass ();
            
            facadeForClient.**Your Methode Name**

        }
    }
```

I hope this is useful for you .